# where should we put key.pem and certificate.pem file for SSL?

Tags: node.js, ssl, pem

I have written below code for SSL but i am getting error "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG " please let me know where to put  key.pem and certificate.pem in my local to get rid of the error

```
if (settings.local) {
    https.createServer({
            key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')

    }, app).listen(https_port);
    console.log("server starting on https://localhost:" + https_port);
```

Comment: *" but i am getting error "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG " "* - where do you get the error, how did you test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems more like a TLS Problem for me. Don't worry, your code can read the certs, otherwise it would throw another Error.

For your first question, I usually put them in certs/{cert.pem, key.pem}

Then second:

You probably tried to send non-SSL data to a server which excepts SSL. Try visiting your site via http, not https.
http://localhost:port instead of https://localhost:port

If that doesn't work either, I got some example code from my projects

```
import https from "http2";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import url from "url";

const options:https.SecureServerOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "certs/key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "certs/cert.pem")),
    minVersion: "TLSv1.3" //Try 1.3 or 1.2
};

const server = https.createSecureServer(options, async (req, res) => {})
.listen(https_port).on("listening", () => {
console.log(`Server listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
```